# Average of compound value or compound of averages?

Tags: mean, error-propagation

Suppose I'm measuring the flow rate of a tube. I measure the time it takes to fill it twice. Each time, I also measure its final volume.

So what is the best approach to calculate the average flow? Calculating each flow and averaging them or averaging the measurements and then calculating the flow?

I'm sure I've read something about this while studying error propagation back in college, but I can't find a good resource on the topic. Any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: Which average do you want?  The average over the two experiments or the time-weighted average?  Both have legitimate uses.

Comment: @whuber I'd like to compute the average flow